# Como mudar o opção selecionada no meu 'combobox' a partir de uma 'li'?

Tags: php, jquery, html5, banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer uma página semelhante a [esta](https://www.chipart.com.br/computadores/monte_seu_pc) onde eu faço o orçamento de um computador.

O ultimo produto do orçamento da ChipArt é o gabinete, o site deles tem uma opção de abrir uma galeria de imagens e selecionar qual gabinete eu quero, como fazer essa seleção e atualizar o 'select' com a opção que foi selecionada?

Comment: Não coloque resolvido no título, aceite(marque ela com um `V`) uma das respostas a qual você mais gostou ou a que resolveu o problema. Se tiver algum dúvida pode consultar [como aceitar uma resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o attributo `selected` do option para definir qual estará selecionado. Veja um exemplo

http://jsbin.com/fogobivaduxo/1/edit?html,output

html:

```
<ul id="selector">
  <li><a href="#" data-target="o1">select 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="o2">select 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-target="o3">select 3</a></li>
</ul>

<select id="s">
  <option></option>
  <option id="o1">1</option>
  <option id="o2">2</option>
  <option id="o3">3</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#selector a').click(function() {
  $("#s").find("#" + $(this).data("target")).attr("selected", true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar um atributo no `li` com o valor da opção e adicionar um evento `onclick`, quando o usuário clicar no `li` você seleciona a opção no `select`, veja o exemplo:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0cvoe68r/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<select name="opcao" id="sel-opcao">
    <option>Selecione</option>
    <option value="1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="3">Opção 3</option>
</select>

<ul id="lista-opcao">
    <li data-value="1">Opção 1</li>
    <li data-value="2">Opção 2</li>
    <li data-value="3">Opção 3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#lista-opcao li').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-value');
    $('#sel-opcao option').filter('[value="'+id+'"]')
                          .prop('selected', true);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Coloque o valor dos *options* em um atributo do `li`, e atualize o valor do `select` com o método `val` do jQuery:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hbgcwjo/)**

HTML

```
<select name="itens" id="itens">
    <option value="1">Gabinete 1</option>
    <option value="2">Gabinete 2</option>
    <option value="3">Gabinete 3</option>
    <option value="4">Gabinete 4</option>
    <option value="5">Gabinete 5</option>
</select>
<hr>
<ul id="escolher">
    <li data-iten="1">Gabinete 1</li>
    <li data-iten="2">Gabinete 2</li>
    <li data-iten="3">Gabinete 3</li>
    <li data-iten="4">Gabinete 4</li>
    <li data-iten="5">Gabinete 5</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#escolher li').click(function(){
    valor = $(this).attr('data-iten');
    $('#itens').val(valor);
});
```