# Adicionando valores dos input's selecionados dentro de um outro input

Tags: php, jquery, html

Eu tenho por exemplo 4 `input`, cada `input` tem um valor especifico ex:

```
*input com os valores
  <input type="radio"  value="1">
  <input type="radio"  value="2">
  <input type="radio"  value="3">
  <input type="radio"  value="4">

*input onde os valores serão adicionados
  <input name="input vazio" type="text"  value="">
```

E eu ainda tenho um outro `input`, e esse `input` inicialmente estará com o valor vazio, e conforme for selecionando os `input`, os valores referente aos `input` selecionados serão adicionados a esse outro `input` vazio, ex:

```
<input type="radio"  value="1">  *esse input foi selecionado, logo o input vazio ficará assim

<input name="input vazio" type="text"  value="1">
```

Suponhamos que eu selecione mais de um botão, quero que adicione os valores de ambos os botoes selecionados, ex:

```
<input type="radio"  value="1">  *esse input foi selecionado
<input type="radio"  value="2">  *esse input foi também foi selecionado
<input type="radio"  value="3">  *esse terceiro também foi selecionado

*logo o input que inicialmente estava vazio ficará assim :     
    <input name="input vazio" type="text"  value="1 2 3">
```

Comment: Tenho a impressão que é parecido/igual a [Como mudar o opção selecionada no meu 'combobox' a partir de uma 'li'?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35435/201)

Comment: Sim, e parecida, só que nesse exemplo que você deu os valores não são adicionados, por que como eu disse, eu gostaria que de adicionar os valores dos inputs selecionados, e nesse exemplo que você passo ele apenas muda um pelo outro.

Comment: Na verdade, me enganei de referencia, era [esta outra resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/35191/201) do abfurlan também, mas no fim o caso é diferente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop checando os marcados e colocar em um `array`, e depois aplicar a função `join` para colocar os valores no `input` de texto separando-os por espaço, exemplo:

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d552ob25/1/)**

**HTML**

```
<label><input type="radio"  value="1" /> 1</label>
<label><input type="radio"  value="2" /> 2</label>
<label><input type="radio"  value="3"/> 3</label>
<label><input name="input vazio" type="text"  value=""/></label>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
    //array que conterá valores dos inputs marcados
    var a = [];
    //faz loop nos inputs marcados
    $('input[type="radio"]:checked').each(function(){
        a.push($(this).val());
    });
    //coloca os valores no input text separando por espaços
    $('input[type="text"]').val(a.join(' '));

});
```

Answer (score 2):

É necessário escutar o [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) dos radio inputs e mudar o [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) do text input conforme esse *change*. Adicionei a classe `my-radio` para esses botões e `my-result` para o input de texto:

```js
$('.my-radio').change(function(){
    var preencher = $('.my-result').val() + $(this).val();
    $('.my-result').val( preencher );
});
$('.my-clear').click(function(){
    $('.my-radio').removeAttr('checked');
    $('.my-result').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="my-radio" type="radio" value="1">
<input class="my-radio" type="radio" value="2">
<input class="my-radio" type="radio" value="3">
<input class="my-radio" type="radio" value="4">
<input class="my-result" name="input vazio" type="text" value="">
<br />
<button class="my-clear">limpar</button>
```